# How can we import live data into excel from any website and then get that data into live python?

Tags: python, excel, dynamic, live

I have some dynamic data in my excel worksheet that keeps updating in 1 to 2 secs, and when I import try to import that data in python with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = “filename.xlsx”
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
print(df)
```

It just prints the last manually saved data.I did turn on the auto save function in excel but that automatically saves the data in OneDrive-Personel/documents. I don’t know how to specify the path to that in python. I want the dynamic data that is in the excel worksheet right now.
I appreciate that you people read this, if you did.
Thanks

Comment: unless you use something that can interface directly with excel and pull data from it directly, you will not see the changes until you manually save the file and reopen it with pandas

Answer (score 0):

Try using VBA to save your file every few seconds instead of autosave. It will imitate the manual save, so it should work for you.

Install `openpyxl` library and then

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('myfile.xlsx') # opens your file
filename = “filename.xlsx”
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
df.to_excel
print(df)
wb.save("myfile.xlsx") # saves the file
```

Comment: I tried using VBA but when I run the Marco code it showed that Marco is not compatible for this file.You guys reply really fast.

Comment: Yeah, that happens, you have to save the file as .xlsm instead of the usual .xlsx the extension is different for macros

Comment: Can I use python to save the excel file in every 50 to 40 secs.

Comment: Can you recommend me any video on that?

Comment: Yeah, here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrGesm7w3G8) for the VBA save tutorial, I'll edit my answer on how you could do it in python

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlwings as xw
import time

i = 1
while i == 1:
    wb = load_workbook('filename.xlsx')
    wb.save("filename.xlsx")
    wbxl = xw.Book('filename.xlsx')

    row_num = 2
    while row_num != 13:
        name = wbxl.sheets['sheet1'].range('A{}'.format(row_num)).value
        print(name)
        row_num += 1

    time.sleep(30)
```

In the code above,
when i save it with the openpyxl module the file has to be closed and when i get the data from the closed excel file the data that i recieve is "N.A.".But if the file is opened then i recieve the required data. Is there any other way to save excel file that works in saving it when it is opened